# Is the Prism Template Studio available for Visual Studio for Mac 8.0?

Tags: prism, visual-studio-mac

I started using the Prism Template Studio with Visual Studio for Mac version 7.x a few days ago.  Today Visual Studio updated and I no longer have access to the handy Prism extensions.

I've tried opening the Extensions Manager and going to the Gallery tab to re-install the Template Studio, but when I search for Prism, nothing shows up.

I expected to find the Prism Template Studio listed.  Is there a version that supports Visual Studio for Mac 8.0 or is there plan to add support?

TIA

Comment: If VS updated today and Prism stopped working, couldn't you at least wait a few days to see if Prism is updated as well? It's pretty difficult for third-party vendors to update their tools before VS itself is updated.